# How to use Entity Framework 4.1 Code First to force a one to one relationship for a one to many relationship in the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I am trying to change EF1 for EF4.1 code first in an application where the **schema cannot be changed** because it is used in SQL Server Replication. The schema is dreadfully poor and in many places describes relationships completely back to front.

What I am trying to do is create a one to one relationship between two classes, but the database schema erroneously maintains the data as a one to many.

```
public class ClassA
{
    public ClassB
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the table ClassB in the database has reference to ClassAId rather than ClassA having a ClassBId as shown here:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ClassA]
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ClassB]
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY
    [ClassAId] [bigint]
```

How to I set up my mapping file that inherits from EntityTypeConfiguration to force this relationship.

```
public class ClassAMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<ClassA>
{
    public ClassA()
    {
        HasKey(f => f.Id);

        // what happens here to force a one to one????
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [Jakub Konecki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/449906/jakub-konecki) for the link to the article, it did not actually contain the answer I was looking for, but it did [link to an earlier post](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/19/entity-association-mapping-with-code-first-one-to-one-shared-primary-key-associations.aspx) in the series where I found the answer.

The way to force this one to one association is as follows:

```
public class ClassAMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<ClassA>
{
    public ClassA()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Id);

        HasOptional<ClassB>(x => x.ClassB)
                .WithRequired()
                .Map(x => x.MapKey("ClassBId"));
    }
}
```

This mapping reads as:

```
"The ClassA entity has an optional association with one ClassB entity, but this association is required for the ClassB entity."
```

Please note that this solution is uni-directional and will not allow the following:

```
ClassB b = new ClassB();
string test = b.ClassA.SomeString;
```

If a bi-directional association is required check out [the link that was found](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/19/entity-association-mapping-with-code-first-one-to-one-shared-primary-key-associations.aspx) which elaborates further.

The article linked by Jakub is part of a [series of posts](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/03/27/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-1-introduction-and-basic-concepts.aspx) which are a good read if you are trying to sort out your EF4.1 associations.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/23/associations-in-ef-code-first-ctp5-part-3-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx

It's an article for CTP5, but I think you will be able to 'translate' fluent API calls to RTm version.